# Why is it more rigourous to take the limit of a variable in an improper integral

Tags: calculus

[image]

Why is it more rigorous to use limits in an improper integral? When would the infinite limit present problems(except divergence)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think by "more rigorous" they mean perform the change of variable and the indefinite integral for a fixed value of $a$ (getting an expression involving $a)$ and **then** you take the limit as $a \rightarrow \infty$ (this being, by definition of the improper integral, what you're supposed to do), rather than "putting in the limit" when you're in the middle of doing the substitution and antiderivative stuff --- this is stuff that you're supposed to have done **before** putting in the limit. Maybe someone with more time than I have can be more detailed for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's "more rigorous to use limits", it's just that the limit is part of the technical definition of an [infinite integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). It's similar to how when you write $1/\infty$, you're not literally dividing by infinity (since division is only defined for real numbers and $\infty$ is not a real number), you're actually referring to the value $\lim_{x\to\infty}1/x$. (This might seem circular since the $\infty$ still appears in "$\lim_{x\to\infty}$", but this infinite limit notation has a special definition different from that of "$\lim_{x\to c}$" for a real number $c$.)

As the book suggests, you're probably safe ignoring this technicality in an introductory calculus course. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)'s an example of how the details of the limit definition can affect the value of the integral.